# Split 2D numpy array horizontally based on percentages

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to be able to split 2D `numpy` **horizontally** into two splits (80% and 20%). I have tried using `np.vsplit()` but it seems it is not made for such a case. For instance, suppose I have the following matrix of size (6,3). I want to split it horizontally into 80% and 20% [roughly (5,3), (1,3)], so I tried something like this:

```
M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9], [10,11,12], [77,54,11], [424,78,98]]
M = np.asarray(M)
arr1 = np.vsplit(M, int(M.shape[0]* 0.8))[0]  # 80% of data goes to arr1
arr2 = np.vsplit(M, int(M.shape[0]* 0.2))[1]  # 20% of data goes to arr2
```

I know this try is incorrect but I can't fix it (actually still learning python). Kindly if someone can help to modify this code. Thank you

Comment: What is your end goal regarding this splitting? If you are doing it for machine learning, sklearn has `train_test_split` which already does this. If you're just splitting 2D matrix deterministicly, then why not just use indexing?

Comment: @Dan Thank you for pointing this out. It is my mistake. I modified the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using **Indexing** (or use [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)):

```
M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9], [10,11,12], [77,54,11], [424,78,98]]
M = np.asarray(M)

split_horizontally_idx = int(M.shape[0]* 0.8) # integer for line selection (horizontal selection)

array1 = M[:split_horizontally_idx , :] # indexing/selection of the 80%
array2 = M[split_horizontally_idx: , :] # indexing/selection of the remaining 20%
```

Comment: It is not used in my current solution. I have mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by slicing the list according to your wish.

```
M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9], [10,11,12], [77,54,11], [424,78,98]]

M = np.asarray(M)

a80=M[:(round(0.8*len(M[:,2]))),:]
a20=M[:(round(0.2*len(M[:,2]))),:]
print(a80,"\n\n",a20)
```